# Add ImageView programmatically after returning to Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, imageview

following situation:

I have a layout with some ImageViews in it. I also have a button to add some new ImageViews. When clicking it you get an overview where you can choose an image. Then the overview activity ends and you return to the fragment. Now the choosen image should be added to the layout.

layout:

```html
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/circle">

        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/square">
        </ImageView>
      
       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/add"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

fragment

```
      @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.addedimg);

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            myLinearLayout.addView(imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

Returning to the fragment from the choosing activity works fine. for simplicity I add a hardcoded imgsource.

Why isn't it showing up on the layout? Do I miss something? Do i need to use the LayoutInflater?

Comment: what is the mLinearLayout here?? in your xml you have not given an id to your linear layout, so i am guessing this cannot be it. Also, y r u using addDragView, try addView instead. let us know a bit more if this does not work, paste some more code from your fragment, activity.

Comment: Sorry. I modified my code a bit in terms of simplicity. Corrected it.

Comment: did it work with addView?

Comment: nope. Trying to observe it with the layout inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it added - you may want to fire up the "layout inspector" - connect your app/mobile to it and observe if something is blocking it or overlaid on this layout.

BTW you are using a drag layout check its parent's layout params.

Answer (score 0):

I compared the properties of an existing imageview and a newly added, invisible one:

new:

```html
mOverScrollMode = 1
mOverlay = null
mPaddingBottom = 0
mPaddingLeft = 0
mPaddingRight = 0
mPaddingTop = 0
mParent = null
mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
mPendingCheckForTap = null
mPerformClick = null
```

existing:

```html
mOverScrollMode = 1
mOverlay = null
mPaddingBottom = 0
mPaddingLeft = 0
mPaddingRight = 0
mPaddingTop = 0
mParent = {DragFrameLayout@6904} "org.mobi.bluemoon.ui.DragFrameLayout{75a40af V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,949 #7f0e00eb app:id/main_layout}"
mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
mPendingCheckForTap = null
mPerformClick = null
```

as we can see there was no parent set to the new one.

the solution was:

```
  dragLayout.addView(imageView);
  dragLayout.addDragView(imageView);
```

Thanks guys!